# Подсчет чисел в строке

Tags: строки, java, числа

Есть строковая переменная s="1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
Пытаюсь посчитать количество чисел следущим образом, не получается,подскажите,пожалуйста, в чем дело.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String s="";
        s=sc.next();
        int k=1;
       for(int i=0;i<s.length();i++)
       {
           char ch=s.charAt(i);

           if(ch==' ')
           {
               k++;
           }
           else
           {

           }
       }

        System.out.print(k);
}
```

Comment: код хоть отформатируйте нормально

Comment: не получается,проще вам скопировать и посмотреть

Comment: между текстом и кодом должна быть пустая строка

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5";
String delimiter = ",";
String[] temp = str.split(delimiter);
int count = temp.length;
```

Comment: Отличный вариант, сначала также пытался сделать,но дело в том,что когда без пробелов строка все ок,но когда в строке есть пробелы,то показывает длину массива 1 элемент. Как тут быть?Мне надо чтобы после ","  стоял пробел.

Comment: @Sergey4590, так а если delimeter сделать вместо запятой ", "? сейчас просто код на java не могу проверить.

Comment: тоже неправильно. единицу выдает

Comment: @Sergey4590Б мне кажется, вы неправы: http://ideone.com/T2YbPr . Заметте, после запятой есть пробел, но выводит 5, а не 1, как вы говорите.

Comment: Согласен, этот код правильный. Просто у меня строка str вводится с клаивиатуры и ответ показывает единицу. Вот весь текст моей программы:

Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        String str =sc.next();
        String delimiter = ",";
        String[] temp = str.split(delimiter);
        int count = temp.length;
        System.out.println(count);

Comment: Нашел в чем проблема! Вместо

String str =sc.next();

пишу 

String str =sc.nextLine();

и все работает. Всем спасибо за помощь.

Answer (score 2):

Вот только может быть одна проблема здесь: числа могут не быть разделены запятыми, или среди разделенных запятыми сущностями могут встретиться символы. Тогда приведенный выше код не сработает. Вот вариант, считающий в строке количество символов в диапазоне от ['0'..'9'] :

```
String str = "1, 2, 3, 4, 5 , a, c , 9, 0";
Integer c = 0;  // счетчик цифр
for(char ch:str.toCharArray())
    if( (int)ch >47 && (int)ch<58 ) c++;
```

Правда, и в этом коде есть "баг": N-значные числа будут восприниматься за N совершенно разных чисел. Но это уже не должно составить труда дописать вам( нужно увеличивать счетчик лишь в том случае, если предыдущий символ не число, а текущий - число ). В прочем, я не знаю вашей задачи целиком, быть может, вам и нужен подсчет лишь одиночных символов-чисел.

Answer (score 1):

Вот решение на С, но язык, как вы понимаете, здесь не принципиален, главное - алгоритм.

```
#include <stdbool.h> // bool
#include <ctype.h> // isdigit
#include <stdio.h> // printf

int count_numbers_in_string(const char* s)
{
    int numbers = 0;
    bool was_at_least_one_digit_after_last_comma = false;
    int c;
    while( c = *s++ ) {
        if( c == ',' ) {
            if( was_at_least_one_digit_after_last_comma ) numbers++;
            was_at_least_one_digit_after_last_comma = false;
        } else if( isdigit(c) ) {
            was_at_least_one_digit_after_last_comma = true;
        }
    }
    return numbers;
}

int main(void)
{
    const char string[] = "1,  2, 333, 44, ,,,5,";
    printf("numbers = %d\n", count_numbers_in_string(string));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что вы некрофилию в самом деле развели?:)

Comment: Справа появилось - я и щёлкнул. На дату не смотрю никогда. Думал, раз спросили - значит, надо. Правильный ответ так ведь и не был дан.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, вопрос, конечно, нечетко описывает допустимые форматы строки, но в очевидных случаях

    1
    1,2
  
и т.п. результат у Вас будет  на 1 меньше правильного.

Наверное, стоило бы предупредить читателей, что любую "грязь" с цифрами Вы тоже считаете за число (ну, да ладно...).

--

Неплохо бы подправить, хоть и вопрос по Java (а то вдруг кто-нибудь нагуглит).

Comment: Да, действительно. Так много раз решал подобные задачи, что не счёл нужным протестировать на разных строках. А зря. По-хорошему, надо вообще тест-сьюты выкладывать, а не main тривиальный. Но я не знаю, какой фреймворк здесь стандарт де-факто. Если такой вообще есть.

Comment: По моему, никаких стандартов тут нет. Да и не надо.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Solution3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String s = "dfgkj12 klj1lk123lk;1234";
        System.out.println(s);
        int count = 0;
        boolean hasNumber = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
            if (Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i))) {
                hasNumber = true;
            }
            if (!Character.isDigit(s.charAt(i)) && hasNumber) {
                count++;
                hasNumber = false;
            }
        }
        if (hasNumber) {
        count++;
        }
        System.out.println("Кол-во чисел в строке = " + count);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hа java. Кажись работает :P

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]